# Is it possible to pass parameter to javascript method from template in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm iterating through the list of objects, i want to render the class name based on the one attribute from the object.
Here is my sample js:

```
<template for:each={tempList} for:item="tempItem">
    <div key={tempItem.label}>
        <span class={testMethod.isActive} >
            {tempItem.label}
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, could you clarify your question? Which method and which parameter do you want to pass attributes to?

Comment: If you give your expected output html and a sample `tempList` that would help!

Comment: Good question. I'd phrase it as how to access the current template `for:each` item in a JavaScript `get`.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a getter that processes the list and adds additional data:

```js
export default class Foo extends LightningElement {
  ...

  @track
  activeIndex = 0;

  get processedList() {
    return this.tempList.map((item, index) => {
      const { label } = item;
      const computedClass = index === this.activeIndex ? 'active' : '';
      return {
        label,
        computedClass,
      };
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<template for:each={processedList} for:item="item">
  <div key={item.label}>
    <span class={item.computedClass}>{item.label}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, I'd also point out that LWCs are the dark ages of software development. Not being able to use expressions in templates is a terrible design choice

Answer (score 0):

My guess - didn't find anything by Googling - is that it is probably simplest to add the data value you need to the list items themselves in the JavaScript that loads the data:

```
let tempItem = ...;
tempItem._class = '...';
```

so as to sidestep the problem:

```
<template for:each={tempList} for:item="tempItem">
    <div class={tempItem._class}>
        ...
```

But would like to know what other approaches are available.

**PS** This [HTML Template Directives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_directives) documentation talks about `for:item`

> injects into the current scope

but doesn't explain whether "scope" is something accessible from the JavaScript or not.